# Differentiability of a summation

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ and $y_1,y_2,...,y_n$ be in $(a,b)$ and $y_i < x_i, 1 \leq i \leq n.$ Show that if $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ then $\sum_{n=1}^{n} (f(x_i)-f(y_i))=f'(c) \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-y_i)$ for some $c$ in $(a,b).$

I think you are suppose to use MVT, but I'm not quite sure how to start this proof. I'm a beginner at proofs.

Answer (score 2):

We know from the MVT that there are $c_k\in (y_k,x_k)$ such that

$$\tag 1 \sum_{k=1}^{n}(f(x_k)-f(y_k)) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}f'(c_k)(x_k-y_k).$$

Divide both sides of $(1)$ by $S= \sum_{k=1}^{n}(x_k-y_k)$ to get

$$\tag 2 \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}(f(x_k)-f(y_k))}{S} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}f'(c_k)\frac{(x_k-y_k)}{S}.$$

Note that on the right of $(2)$ each $(x_k-y_k)/S > 0$ and that $\sum_k (x_k-y_k)/S = 1.$ Thus the right side of $(2)$ is an average of the values $f'(c_1), \dots, f'(c_n).$ This average must lie between the smallest $f'(c_k)$ and the largest $f'(c_k).$ It follows from Darboux that this average equals $f'(c),$ for some $c\in (a,b).$ In other words,

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}f'(c_k)\frac{(x_k-y_k)}{S} = f'(c)$$

for some $c\in (a,b).$ Multiply the last equality by $S$ and use $(1)$ to get the desired result.

Comment: Could you explain a little more how this follows from MVT?

Comment: $f(x) - f(y) = f'(c)(x-y), c\in (y,x).$

Comment: I meant how does it give the result. Could you show the multiplying by S step as well to show the result, please?

Comment: I edited it a little bit; maybe it's clearer now.